# Is there a guideline telling users not to golf someone else's post in an edit?

Tags: discussion, answers, editing

I really hate it when a user thinks it's okay to edit someone else's post to golf it. Is this included in the guidelines for suggesting edits at all?

The post in question: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/24657

Note that one user correctly rejected the edit, listing the reason, but it was approved in the end anyway.

Comment: Just a note, the reason listed by the rejecting reviewer, `This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.` is completely inaccurate. My edit suggestion was actually based on the highest-rated comment on the answer, after which mbomb had already asked "do you want me to change it?" which the question's OP had affirmed, so I was making a good faith edit to do so. As far as the linked meta question, in this case the content of the edit carries 0 possibility of breaking the code.

Comment: That said, it was not my intent to step on your toes, and I apologize for any offense. I was only attempting to satisfy the question's OP. And I did only the 8 byte golf, not the 5 byte one, because I knew the 8 byte one could not be wrong, but I don't know that for certain with the 5 byte one.

Comment: [This meta answer](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76/41501) echoes my motivation.

Comment: @DanHenderson That question is talking about creating your own answer that is golfed more. In general, it's better to never edit someone else's answer with a golf, since you obviously wouldn't do it in the same way as someone else. Even if other people say they'd like it edited, it's up to me. Give me a couple days to edit it. It's my answer, after all.

Comment: I chose to make an edit suggestion, incorporating the golfing of the [existing, highly-rated comment](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/59347/shortest-infinite-loop-producing-no-output/59415?noredirect=1#comment143035_59415), rather than submitting a new answer, because the difference was so minor, and I didn't want to look like I was rep-fishing. So that question is *entirely* appropriate.

Comment: It was already an edit suggestion. IN THE COMMENT. You can then just wait for me to make an edit.

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice

Comment: @DanHenderson I am being nice. I'm attempting to reiterate everything I've already said that you appear to have missed. The edit was already suggested in the comments, so you don't need to suggest an actual edit. Just wait for the user (me) to edit his (my) own post. You didn't even wait an entire day.